# How can I split this string easily

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have the following string:

```
"<--something--><++something++><**something**>"
```

The string can have an arbitrary number of "somethings" , even just once.

I need to split it like so:

```
["<--something-->", "<++something++>", ...]
```

But I don't know how to proceed best.

I would do something like `string.split("><")` but then I would have:

```
["<--something--", "++something++", ...]
```

And with `string.split(/(><)/)` I'd get:

```
["<--something--", "><", "++something++", "><", ...]
```

I can think of a few less-than-optimal solutions, but I want really elegant one.

Comment: @Jack oh that sounds like a good suggestion.

Comment: If you want to get the inner contents (stuff inside of `< >`) - http://jsfiddle.net/5qwNV/

Comment: @Ian I needed it all but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Please tell me this is not HTML. If not, do tell me *what* it is :)

Comment: @Jack it's not HTML, it's part of an in-house templating language that has a very specific purpose so I could tell you but it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = '<--something--><++something++><**something**>',
    p = s.match(/(<[^>]+>)/g);
console.log(p); // ["<--something-->", "<++something++>", "<**something**>"]
```

That's only assuming that each "token" will never have a `>` within. So, it will fail with the following:

```
<--some>thing--><++something++><**something**>
       ^ problematic
```

I would like to stress that if you're using this to parse HTML, **stop right there**. Regex isn't the right solution if you're looking to grab specific elements out of HTML. instead, place the content in a hidden `<div>` (or something) and use the native DOM accessors.

Answer (score 4):

You're not splitting the string, you are matching it.

Try this:

```
string.match(/<(.)\1[^>]+?\1\1>/g)
```

This will match `<`, two of a kind, then find the same two of a kind and `>` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This expression should do it:

```
"<--something--><++something++><**something**>".match(/<([+*-])\1.*?\1\1>/g)
```

It matches an opening angle bracket, followed by two identical characters (taken from set of `+`, `-` and `*`, but you could just use `.` to match any; it ends with the same two characters and a closing angle bracket.

Answer (score -1):

solution:

```
var a = "<--something--><++something++><**something**>";
a.match(/\<(\-|\+|\*)+something(\-|\+|\*)+\>/g);
```

result:

```
["<--something-->", "<++something++>", "<**something**>"]
```

Comment: No, you're creating match groups. This will not do what I want. Also, I didn't mean `something` to be literal.

Comment: You didnt said you dont need matching groups, and the something you can replace with ([\w])+